# Have a folder with dynamic content automatically controlled by TFS

Tags: version-control, tfs

I have a web project that has a folder with dynamic generated content with 4000+ files, and those files must be on source control.

I would like these files to be automatically included in the project so I can upload them to source control instead of me having to track them down and add them to project.

An option would be to exclude all and them re-include them before a check in but it takes too much time in Visual Studio.

Another question, can I solve it if I use GIT instead of TFS source control?

Comment: may be one option is to autoamte task with tf.exe https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0(v=vs.100).aspx (for example tf add . /recursive)

Comment: @matap, what's the file type of these dynamic generated files? If that file type is not in the excluded list in the .tfignore file, these files will be in the Included Pending Changeset list by default. And they will be checked in to TFS Version Control if you do the check in operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GIT, when you open a version controlled project, you'll see the new added files will appear in "Untracked Files" in "Changes" tab, after selecting "Add All", the new added files will be added and ready for Commit. Check: http://incyclesoftware.com/2013/08/version-control-with-tfs-2013-git-repository/

Using TFVC, you can add new files from VS, or TFS Power Tool, or use tf.exe command line. Check http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/adding-content-to-source-control and  http://nullablecode.com/2013/01/tfs-windows-shell-tfs-power-tools/